# Why my submit button submit twice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, double-submit-problem

HTML Page

```
<body>
  <form id="form1" action="Default.aspx" method="post">
    <input runat="server" id="txtuser" type="text" />
    <input runat="server" id="txtpwd" type="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
 </form>
</body>
```

Code-behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
        Login();
   }
}

private void Login()
{
   if (checkUser(Request.Params["txtuser"],Request.Params["txtpwd"]))
   {
        Response.Redirect("Success.aspx");//if success
   }
}
```

I am developing a web page for old mobile version (like nokia N70) facing a problem. When I submit my username and password then check user return true to redirect to a new page. But it won't redirect to `success.aspx`. So I debug point on the `Response.Redirect` code, it can stop there and I continue run become error because getting the username&password null. Then I realized it loaded the page twice. How to solve it?

Comment: i think it is ur problem on checkUser method

Comment: Do you use forms authentication and the Success Page is not authorized? You better use ASP.NET Forms Auth like explained here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx

Comment: Is your HTML Page the Default.aspx page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to login when there IS a PostBack. Not the other way around.

Change

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
```

to

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
```

Make sure you have set `AutoEventWireup` to true in Code Front:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"...
```

otherwise Page_Load is never fired.

Comment: sani if the Page.IsPostBack return false how i fire the login function?

Comment: an input type="submit" fires a postback as well. Your first part of the answer is correct, but not the 2nd (even if I would use an server control as well).

Comment: @slfan: of course... too early in the morning... no coffee yet... ;)

Comment: for submit button with tag runat="server" i dont know why not working on old mobile browser.That why i not put on there .

Comment: runat="server" is executed on the server. It has nothing to do with the browser. It should render an input type="submit" on the browser in any case.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Forms Authentication in a proper way, like explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx)

You should do something like this for your redirect:

```
if (checkUser(userName.Text, password.Text))
{
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName.Text, false);
}
```

Comment: then how i redirect to the path i want, like success.aspx

Comment: You navigate to Success.aspx. In case you are not logged in, you will be redirected to Login.aspx, where you do your checkUser. An authentication cookie will be genereated so that you don't have to login again.